# Questions about nouns that are always plural

Tags: questions, pluralia-tantum

Is it correct to ask about nouns that are always plural and denote things that physically consist of two parts (scissors, trousers, binoculars) like this:

> What are these?

I'd say that such a question is acceptable if the speaker wants to emphasize the fact of comprising two parts, not one.

Comment: There is a related question on EL&U: [Are words like “scissors” plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/211713/are-words-like-scissors-plural). One answer there suggests they are [duals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_(grammatical_number)) I'm not really  sure about that for English though...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: Yes.

If, say, I wanted to know who owned a particular pair of scissors, I might point to them or hold them up and say, "Whose are these?" I wouldn't say "Whose is this?" because scissors is plural.

To be pedantic, "What are these?" is more problematic. If I don't know what the object is, I may not know that it is conventionally referred to in the plural even though there only appears to be one thing there.

Comment: Then again, "What is this? This is a pair of scissors.", if you thought of them that way.

Comment: @user3169 Fair enough. I suppose in general a  plural can be "converted" into a singular by using a group noun. Like, "Whose pencils are these?" versus "Whose box of pencils is this?"